# Solve $y''-2\frac{y'}{x}+9x^4y=\sin x.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y''-2\frac{y'}{x}+9x^4y=\sin x.$$

Well I know the solution will be the sum of general and complementary solutions, but I have no idea how to solve this homogeneous equation without sinx. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try making the substitution $y=e^{rx}$ for the homogeneous case, and realize that $e^{rx}$ is never $0$ for any real $x$.

Comment: This substitution yields no results, as i get
$9e^2x^4+r^2*x^2-rx-2re=0$

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be any $e^2$, but the reason it doesn't work is because of the $1/x$ term. The substitution should give $r^2e^{rx}-2re^{rx}/x+9x^4e^{rx}$, but nothing further can be said here because factoring out e^{rx} gives $r^2-2r/x+9x^4$, so another method is needed.  That being said, I think Robert Israel is right below, although you might try the method of undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the change of independent variables $t = x^3$ works.

But I don't think you'll find a closed-form solution to the inhomogeneous equation: the antiderivative you get out of reduction of order or variation of parameters is not elementary.

Comment: I dont quite get how $t=x^3$ works here. And wolfram alpha shows that solution to homogenous equation is $c1sin(x^3)+c2cos(x^3)$

Comment: If $y(x) = g(x^3)$, then $y'(x) = 3 x^2 g'(x^3)$ and 
$y''(x) = 6 x g'(x^3) + 9 x^4 g''(x^3)$, so $y'' - 2 y'/x + 9 x^4 y = 9 x^4 (g''(x^3) + g(x^3))$.

Comment: Can I assume that this is equal to 0 when $g′′(x^3)+g(x^3)=0$?